# Angular Formly validating same input

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I want to validate if two input fields(email) and validate that they return the same value using Formly. So far, I've managed to check if the value of the validate input filed is equal to the email field.

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'email',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Email'
    }
  },
  {
    key: 'validateEmail',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Validate Email',
    },
    validators:{
      macAddress: {
        expression: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope){
          return modelValue === scope.model["email"]; 
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
```

The JS Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/yitolo/edit?html,js,output)

But, this validation only occurs when the second field is being filled. Is there a way to do this validation when the email is being filled?

Comment: What type of validation do want to run when the first email field is filled? Check for valid email format or compare it with the validateEmail field?

Comment: @Obaid I want to compare the validateEmail field with the new value in the email field. Then if the validateEmail is invalid(ie - in-equal to the new value), I want the mark it as invalid

Comment: @nipuna777 since the model is not set until the validations passes, you cannot validate two-ways. See: http://jsbin.com/wagane/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Obaid I see, but is there a way to change the validation of the validateEmail from within the email element?

Comment: Also, I used to do this by watching the value of 'email' in the scope, and if set $valid there. To do this, we'll need the input fields name. Which is now generated by Formly... Is there a way to replicate this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an example of doing this under angular-formly website. Please check this one:

http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/matching-two-fields

Just note that the current version of formly has an issue (that I am also strangling with) and trying to find a solution. This is the [issue on github](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/issues/523), however it should NOT affect what YOU are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: While it works, it still has the same problem that the example I've posted. When you enter an email in the first field, and then enter the email again in the second one, It gets validated as expected. 
But, the problem is, that once validated, we can change the first email without triggering the 'verify email' fields validator. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: I just went through the issue on GitHub. That's pretty much exactly the issue I'm facing. The JSFiddle by Kent [here](http://jsbin.com/rokoci/edit?html,js,output), seems to work as intended.

Comment: Yes that's why I wrote all that. the solution you are looking for is `extras: { validateOnModelChange: true }`. Here is a working jsbin: https://jsbin.com/tabise/edit?html,js,output -- NOTICE: its on v.7.1.2

Comment: Alrighty, So, when the bug is fixed, that should work on the current version as well?

Comment: It should work for "normal cases" but not for repeatedSection unless someone fixes that as well.